# How do i compare only the first 8 caracters in cells

Tags: vba, excel

In the macro below data in Sheet1 cells in column "X" is compared with data in column "A" on sheet2. If there is a match the entire corresponding row from sheet1 will be copied to sheet3.
I need a peace of code that in this macro will only compare the first 8 caracters.

```
Sub CopyMatch()

Dim StartingScreenUpdateValue As Boolean
Dim StartingEventsValue As Boolean
Dim StartingCalculations As XlCalculation

With Application
StartingScreenUpdateValue = .ScreenUpdating
StartingEventsValue = .EnableEvents
StartingCalculations = .Calculation
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Dim varTestValues As Variant
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
Dim sh3 As Worksheet

Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set sh3 = Sheets("Sheet3")

With sh2
varTestValues = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

End With

With sh1
.Range("X1", .Range("X" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) _
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(varTestValues),     Operator:=xlFilterValues
.Range("X2", sh1.Range("X" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) _
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy sh3.Range("A2")
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = StartingScreenUpdateValue
.EnableEvents = StartingEventsValue
.Calculation = StartingCalculations
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Look at `LEFT` `RIGHT` `MID` these should assist.  Googling your question, gave some results to :)

Comment: thank you Nathan but were do i put this in the macro. This goes above my knowledge .

Comment: Something like `varTestValues = Left(varTestValues, 8)` right after you have set `varTestValues`

Comment: Sorry Tim, cant get it to work

Comment: Thats because you are loading in test values as an array. You need to compare each element within your array using the Left() function. For example, if you wanted to check the first element of the array you would do "If Left(varTestValues, 8) = Left(TestCase, 8) Then" where TestCase is the value you are comparing against.

Comment: Thank you Brandon

Comment: Still cant get it working. Is there anyone ho can put the richt code in the macro. Thank you so much